# Create Android Sqlite data base from SenchaTouch

Tags: android, sencha-touch, android-sqlite

Hi I am new bie to sencha touch I have requirement for creating the andorid sqlite database from sencha touch,I am building the andorid apk with phone gap ,can i use phonegap api in sencha touch for creating native android sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for : http://hansjar.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-easily-add-prepopulated-sqlite.html